# infopath error: The form cannot be submitted because of an error.

Tags: infopath

I am working with sharepoint 2010 and using Infopath designer 2013.  I am using sharepoint list as my data source.

I am getting an error: The form cannot be submitted because of an error.

InfoPath cannot submit the form.
An error occurred while the form was being submitted.
Access is denied.

When i click the submit button i get the error.  Not sure why i am getting this error.  Any help will be appreciated.  I added the url for the sharepoint site to the trusted sites.  I

Thanks,

michael

Answer (score 0):

If your form has any code behind, then it will likely require a site collection administrator to publish it.  If that doesn't work, it's possible your farm administrator has done the same as mine and disabled the ability to publish forms with Code Behind.  If that is the case, then only a farm administrator can publish the form as trusted.

**EDIT**
In my case, I was able to get my security team to issue me a 'code signing certificate'. With that certificate attached to the form, I was able to publish a code behind form to Sharepoint 2010 as the site collection administrator.